# How to make the AppModule in one project exportable and import it in another angular cli project?

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I am quiet new to the npm and angular stuff. I have created an angular cli project, which I want to export the AppModule and use it in another cli project. If anyone know how I could do it? I have add export {AppModule from './app.component' in the main.ts file already. But it doesn't work.

Thank you very much in advanced!

Comment: It seems you need to have a angular library project, it is a feature request for angular cli and there is a thread going on this [Create boilerplate for library](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1692) and [Library Support and Boilerplate](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6510), Cheers!!

Comment: thank you very much, I use this library to create the module, but have some aot problems when importing it in the project. But I finally make it works with angular cli, https://medium.com/@ngl817/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e I just follow this post and now it works perfect. Thank you all the same!

Comment: Cool, you are using library called `ng-packagr` , hopefully some day we will get similr behaviour out of the box from angular-cli, Cheers!!